# How to get pass the i from a for loop to the id tag in jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have a some inputs with different ids as you see down here

```
<tr>

    <td><input type="number" id="cell1" ></td>
    <td><input type="number" id="cell2" ></td>
    <td><input type="number" id="cell3" ></td>



    <td><input type="number" id="cell4"></td>
    <td><input type="number" id="cell5"></td>
    <td><input type="number" id="cell6"></td>



    <td><input type="number" id="cell7" ></td>
    <td><input type="number" id="cell8" ></td>
    <td><input type="number" id="cell9" ></td>

</tr>
```

Now I want to use jquery to restrict the number the user enters in the inputs with something like this

```
for(var i = 0 ; i <= 81 ; i++) {


    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#cell" , i).change(function () {

            var n = $("#cell",i).val();
            console.log($("#cell", i));
            if (n < 1)
                $("#cell", i).val(1);
            if (n > 9)
                $("#cell" , i).val(9);
        });
    });

}
```

But it doesn't get the ids. How can I pass the i variable to "#cell"?

Comment: `$(document).ready(` does not belong inside a loop. if you use `let` or `const` instead of `var`, your value for `i` will be preserved.. however, you don't need the loop at all, which would also eliminate the problem.

Comment: Try `"#cell"+i`

Comment: I think you mean `$("#cell" + i)`, using `+` rather than `,`, but as @KevinB notes, you don't need the loop. Instead, just change the HTML to use the `min` and `max` attributes.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Because I have lots of cells, it was hard to add a min and max to all of them. Thats why I was looking for another solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things. You likely want this selector - id starts with cell

```js
$(function() {
  $("[id^=cell]").on("input",function() {
    const val = this.value
    if (val < 0) this.value = 1
    if (val > 0) this.value = 9
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>

      <td><input type="number" id="cell1"></td>
      <td><input type="number" id="cell2"></td>
      <td><input type="number" id="cell3"></td>



      <td><input type="number" id="cell4"></td>
      <td><input type="number" id="cell5"></td>
      <td><input type="number" id="cell6"></td>



      <td><input type="number" id="cell7"></td>
      <td><input type="number" id="cell8"></td>
      <td><input type="number" id="cell9"></td>

    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

HTML version

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>

      <td><input type="number" id="cell1" min=1 max=9></td>
      <td><input type="number" id="cell2" min=1 max=9></td>
      <td><input type="number" id="cell3" min=1 max=9></td>
      <td><input type="number" id="cell4" min=1 max=9></td>
      <td><input type="number" id="cell5" min=1 max=9></td>
      <td><input type="number" id="cell6" min=1 max=9></td>
      <td><input type="number" id="cell7" min=1 max=9></td>
      <td><input type="number" id="cell8" min=1 max=9></td>
      <td><input type="number" id="cell9" min=1 max=9></td>

    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @mplungjan Thanks your solution works. But it is my understanding that $("[id^=cell]") will get all of cells. if I want to something on a specific cell, how do I go about it?
(Since i have lots of cells I can't just do $("#col3") for example)

Comment: It will get all cells with ID starting with cell.
That is what I expected you wanted. If not, update your question

Answer (score 0):

First, move your loop inside the `$document.ready`

Then simply append `i` to the id prefix to make the correct `querySelector` for the cell.

Although it doesn't answer your question you could also use the [min and max](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_min.asp) attributes to accomplish your task.

Here is a working example of appending the loop counter `i`.

```js
// create 81 inputs for demo purposes
$(document).ready(function () {
  var row= $('#myrow');
  for(var i = 0 ; i <= 81 ; i++)
  {
    row.append($('<td/>').append('<input type="number" />').attr("id", "cell" + i));
  }
});

$(document).ready(function () {
  for(var i = 0 ; i <= 81 ; i++) {
$("#cell"+ i).change(function (e) {
  var input= $(e.target);
  var n = input.val();
  if (n < 1)
    input.val(1);
  else if (n > 9)
    input.val(9);               
  });
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<table>
<tr id='myrow'>
</tr>
</table>
```